# Rails EC2 testp2.czar.bielawa.pl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

i deployed a rails app on a EC2 instance and on this morning when i clicked on a section of the app redirected to this http://testp2.czar.bielawa.pl/.

i would like to know if this is a malware or what?

because this link is not part of the app.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes its type malware, you might not be the actual target is rather that your server might be used for source of spam, port scanning and DDoS attacks.

There is pretty extensive abuse list for

> http://testp2.czar.bielawa.pl/

See here.http://www.abuseipdb.com/report-history/185.25.151.159

For getting rid of this follow the great instructions from serverfault below.

https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Alternatively if there is nothing important there just delete the EC2 and start again

Comment: thank you very much @Kimmo Hintikka. and have any way to remove this malware? thanks